# Stay on 5.19 HWE kernel

Tags: apt, kernel, 22.04

Recently `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` on 22.04 switched to using the 6.2 kernel series form 5.19, which doesn't work well on my hardware.

How can I stay on the 5.19 series? I guess I could just pin myself on the current 5.19 kernel (5.19.0-50) but will there be further patches to this series?

I could uninstall the hwe package but that would put me back on 5.15.

Comment: You have correctly identified your options. You have overlooked nothing. When 5.19 support ceases soon, there will be no further security patches.

Comment: I have the same issue, on a Dell Latitude E7470 the webcam image flickers too much using kernel 6.2, no issue while using 5.19. IMHO Kernel 6.2 has some driver issue, which is not a big problem, but I need to switch to an older kernel version: 5.15 will be fine anyway. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu no longer provides security fixes for the 5.19 kernel from

- [Ubuntu 22.10 (*its EOL*)](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/)
- 22.04 using HWE (*those systems are now supported on 6.2 from 23.04*)

so unless you're asking about a 5.19 **OEM** kernel that is still supported (*I'm not aware of one, but I don't monitor the various OEM kernel stacks close enough*), you've the GA or HWE kernel stack as your options (*unless your hardware can utilize an OEM kernel stack option*).

I agree with @user535733's prior advice (*except I see 5.19 as already EOL in Ubuntu given 6.2 has already replaced it on jammy*).

Comment: If @user535733 wants to write an answer; I'll remove this one; since its really no extra detail except for 5.19 was from the now *unsupported* 22.10 system (*that stack gets used by HWE stack from prior cycle's LTS for ~six months which have no ended*) & a fridge link